# HWIOAuthBundle Google - Don't have all data that I want

Tags: php, symfony, google-api, hwioauthbundle

I'm using HWIOAuthBundle for google and I can sign in and login with it. But I need to have all informations about the user (works, educations, skills, etc) and the only thing that I receive is :

```
array (size=11)
  'id' => string 'XXXXXXXXXXX' (length=21)
  'email' => string 'XXXXXXX' (length=19)
  'verified_email' => boolean XXXXX
  'name' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=13)
  'given_name' => string 'XXXX' (length=6)
  'family_name' => string 'XXXX' (length=6)
  'link' => string 'XXXX' (length=45)
  'picture' => string 'XXXXXXX' (length=92)
  'gender' => string 'XXXX' (length=4)
  'locale' => string 'XXXXX' (length=2)
  'hd' => string 'XXXXX' (length=12)
```

in my config.yml, I have two scopes that are :

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
```

Google+ API is well activated in my app on Google. When I try with the Google API explorer with my account and the same scopes, I find all data that I want...

Please, can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

If someone want to do this, you need to add an infos_url in the HWIOAuthBundle's config.yml, this is not in the doc and nobody talk about that on the web, so for all datas you need to add this :

```
#HWIOAuth
hwi_oauth:
firewall_name: hwio_oauth
resource_owners:
    google:
        type: google
        client_id: XXX
        client_secret: XXX
        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
        options:
            access_type: offline
            infos_url: "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me"
```